# Is it possible to capture an expression's content before it's evaluated when passed as arguments to a function?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a simple function that takes in a conditional, then returns something.

E.g.:

```
bool is_even(int num){
   return (num % 2 == 0);
}
void Foo(conditional)
{
    if(conditional)
        std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
}
```

Is it possible to get the arguments or the expression as a whole that went into the Conditional before it's evaluated by the function?

So by that I mean, if the conditional was is_even(2), can I get the expression "is_even(2)" before it's evaluated, instead of the true value(True)?

Comment: Are you programming in C or C++?

Comment: No. BTW, `return num %2 ==0;`

Comment: @Bathsheba I cleared it up to be C++, sorry.  I only included C due to C-style macros being a possible way of capturing this.

Comment: In what form would you expect this expression?  And do you have experience in some other language that would lead you to believe this was possible?

Comment: You can't do this in C++ (neither in C BTW). Once the program is compiled there are no more expressions. What are you _actually_ trying to do?

Comment: You could pass a lambda, but you can't "examine" the contents of the lambda.

Comment: With your debugger, sure :)

Comment: What do you mean by "get the expression"? In what form?

Comment: What if you passed a macro that stringified the conditional, then evaluated the expression inside the function?

i.e. #define STRINFIFYARGS(X) arg, #x, then say Foo(STRINGIFY(x)) then handle printing the expression as well as evaluating the expression?

Is this ridiculously weird

Comment: You can't evaluate a string as an expression. (Without calling a compiler)

Comment: I mean getting the literal expression as it went into the function to clarify to all.  As in, being able to print "is_even(2)" if that was the exact argument that went into Foo. @ScottHunter

Comment: @MichaelWalz I'm honestly just curious for the sake of learning, there's no end game goal here

Comment: @Fields: Thanks for the clarification. A solution in C would have been very different.

Comment: `assert` works a bit like that, but it just does `#define assert(COND) __assert(COND, #COND, __FILE__, __LINE__)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way would be to use a class that overloads the `()` operator to a `bool`:

```
struct Bar
{
     bool operator()() const;
};
```

and write

```
template <typename Y>
void Foo(const Y& y)
{
    if(y()){
        std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

You can then encapsulate any state into `Bar`. If you don't like the fact that you need to write `y()` at the point of evaluation, you could tweak the syntax further by defining a *conversion* operator to `bool` instead:

```
struct Bar
{
    operator bool() const;
};
```

and write

```
template <typename Y>
void Foo(const Y& y)
{
    if (y){
        std::cout << "Bar" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

In doing this, you are stumbling upon *actors*, and the foundations of that wonderful piece of C++ engineering Boost Spirit. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model and https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.spirit